# Why do people attack me every time my guard finishes?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I swear I didn’t do anything wrong. Almost every time my shield finishes, someone raids my village. Do they know when my shield finishes? Like, the same person raided my village almost two times a day. What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your base defense probably isn't very strong. As soon as your guard ends your village can be attacked and if your base looks easy to beat then you'll be attacked very quickly. I'd look up a good base layout for your town hall level.

You should also try to use your resources as soon as possible. The more resources you have, the more incentive people will have to attack you.

One final point is the amount of trophies you have. The more trophies you have compared to your opponent the more trophies they gain on a win. If you've been pushing trophies really hard you might want to slow down a little bit or you'll be outmatched.